# chosen-select not initiating within document.ready. Unable to reset chosen-select

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I have a sample  list on which i am using javascript chosen plugin.

On all the tutorials I have seen, they initiate chosen within $(document).ready function but whenever i try to do that, it gives me an error:
"Uncaught type error...chosen is not a function" .

If i initiate outside of it, It works fine..

Next Issue is if i try to reset the list using val("").trigger("chosen:updated")
it doesnt do anything..

My code is below:

```
         <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>


        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">


            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">


            <select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Search for Numbers" style="width: 300px; height: 20px">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
            </select>
            <button id="btn">click me to reset</button>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
                });


                $("#btn").click(function () {
                    console.log("Button Clicked To Reset");
                    $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
                    $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("liszt:updated");

                });

            </script>
        </asp:Content>
```

Am I making some simple mistake? could it be loading jquery or chosen thats causing the problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

HTML Rendered:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1"><title>



</title>

    <script src='/Scripts/common.js'                       type="text/javascript"></script>  
    <script src='/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1-vsdoc.js'           type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'             type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jq171 = jQuery.noConflict();
    </script>
    <script src='/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js'          type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js'                type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js'             type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.debug.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/js.cookie.js'                    type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='/Scripts/breadcrumb-messageSender.js'  type="text/javascript"></script>

    <link id="Link1" href="../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link2" href="../Content/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link3" href="../Content/jquery.ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link4" href="../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link5" href="../Content/jquery.ui.datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link7" href="../Content/Icons/scss/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link id="Link6" href="../Content/Styles/eps-site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link type="text/css" href="/Content/TelerikStyles/telerik.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/TelerikStyles/telerik.telerik.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="/Content/Styles/eps-telerik-grid.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!--Hayri-->
    <script src='/Scripts/EpsUtils.js' type="text/javascript"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        addExpanderEventHandlers(null);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">



  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">



    <select  class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Search for Numbers" style="width: 300px; height: 20px" >
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>


    <button id="btn">click me to reset</button>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
          $('.chosen-select').chosen();
        });




        $("#btn").click(function () {
      console.log("Button Clicked To Reset");
      $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("liszt:updated");

        });
    </script>


    </div>

    <!-- This should be exact sequence for scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.1.custom.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
 <!--this one has jquery-1.4.2.min.js-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">
```

in this:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.7/chosen.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
        var jq183 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

And change this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
});

$("#btn").click(function () {
    console.log("Button Clicked To Reset");
    $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
    $('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

in this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jq183(document).ready(function () {
      jq183('.chosen-select').chosen();

      jq183("#btn").click(function () {
        console.log("Button Clicked To Reset");
        jq183('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("chosen:updated");
        jq183('.chosen-select').val("").trigger("liszt:updated");
      });
    });
</script>
```

If it works I can elaborate more on what went wrong and what might be a cleaner solution for you. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve. However, I am using MVC 2 webform with Master Page to create the aspx view pages. (Something i have no control over at the moment, need to use it). I added the https and also added the scripts to the <head> of Master page, I'm still unable to reproduce this behavior in my page.

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML if it's not too big? You can get this by opening your page, then right-click "View page source" (or something like that) and post that.

Comment: Ah ok, that is very useful @NAKDeveloper I think I know what is going wrong. I will update my answer tomorrow. Just got home late from a long day.

Comment: I'll try it out first thing on Monday.